# Store parameters in object and call in a function

Tags: r

Say I have an operation that I want to perform on some data, for example, taking the means of some columns. Is there any way that I can store the function parameters, in the example below, `trim` and `na.rm` in an object, and simply call that object when using the function, instead of having to type the parameters in each time I take the mean? Please note I'm not trying to use apply, summarise all, or any of those types of functions that are more efficient in the example below.

```
## sample data
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                  y = 11:20)

## traditional appraoch
mean(dat$x, trim = 0.3, na.rm = T)
mean(dat$y, trim = 0.3, na.rm = T)

## desired functionality
parameters <- list(trim = 0.3, na.rm = T)
mean(dat$x, parameters)
mean(dat$y, parameters)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap it in `do.call`

```
do.call(mean,  c(list(dat$x), parameters))
```

Or

```
do.call(mean,  c(dat['x'], parameters))
```